# Capture javax.net.debug to file

Tags: java, log4j

I need to save the javax.net.debug=all output that is created to a file. I'm using log4j and I tried creating a logging proxy as in the code example below; however, it is not picking up the info. I am not sure where the javax.net.debug is being printed to. I tried capturing system.out and system.err this way but neither worked. Thanks for your help.

```
public class StdOutErrLog {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StdOutErrLog.class);

    public static void tieSystemOutAndErrToLog() {
        System.setOut(createLoggingProxy(System.out));
        System.setErr(createLoggingProxy(System.err));
    }

    public static PrintStream createLoggingProxy(final PrintStream realPrintStream) {
        return new PrintStream(realPrintStream) {
            public void print(final String string) {
                realPrintStream.print(string);
                logger.info(string);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the subsystem makes its copy of the values and you are too late when switching. Try doing this first in your main.

EDIT

OK - i missed completely your idiom. I think you should not use this inner class. You should define a PrintStream instance on an OutputStream that creates a new log entry upon every "\n". The way you do it now misses a lot of possibilities to "print around" your instance.

```
package de.mit.stackoverflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class LogOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (b == '\n') {
            log(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
        } else {
            sb.append((char) b);
        }
    }

}
```

and then do

```
    OutputStream os = new LogOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
    System.setOut(ps);
```

You maybe still want to include a reference to the previous stream - left as excercise :-)

Comment: Yeah, it is is my main. It is the first call before I set the debug option for the SSL.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but it's possible that overriding `print(String)` is not enough.  For example, there is also `print(Object)`, etc., not to mention the various `append()` and `format()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Dedicated for those who came here seeking for a solution and none of those have worked.
I faced this problem with Tomcat 9 application running with jdk8 (source code compliance level is 1.7, configured LOG4J and Tomcat JULI logging), so my solution is based on that, however this tip is universal:

> Always check documentation and investigate code sources.

Searching by some specific keywords from ssl trace log i've found out that system property "javax.net.debug" is used in [SSLLogger.java](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLLogger.java) (newer jdk, i.e 11) and in [Debug.java](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/Debug.java) (older jdk, i.e. 7).
I was lucky enough to find jdk11 sources first, so there i've found descriptive comments (while older haven't):

> If the system property "javax.net.debug" is not defined, the debug
> logging  is turned off.  If the system property "javax.net.debug" is
> defined as empty, the debug logger is specified by
> System.getLogger("javax.net.ssl"), and applications can customize
> and configure the logger or use external logging mechanisms.  If
> the system property "javax.net.debug" is defined  and non-empty, a
> private debug logger implemented in this class is used.

I've added "-Djavax.net.debug" VM argument to Tomcat server and SSL trace log output have slightly changed (and became less verbose).

To control what this package logger will output i've modified Tomcat server *logging.properties*:

- add new logging handler (5 is sequence number, i.e. i had 4 logging handlers before):

  `5ssl.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST`

  `5ssl.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs`

  `5ssl.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = ssl.`

  `5ssl.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 2`
- add this handler to handlers property:

  `handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 5ssl.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`
- and, finally, override SSL default logger:

  `javax.net.ssl.level = FINEST`

  `javax.net.ssl.handlers = 5ssl.org.apache.juli.FileHandler`

Now my custom logger is (almost) working similarly to native SSLLogger with debug level 'all'.

**Important** difference is that more verbose messages like  'ssl,trustmanager' or 'ssl,plaintext' are missing.

Native logger output:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|47|http-nio-8081-exec-5|2022-06-28 17:05:43.051 EEST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:474|Raw read (
  0000: 6B 38 AA 29 C2 5B 2B 22   AD 2B 23 3B A9 EA A8 EA  k8.).[+".+#;....
  0010: E0 BF 64 4A 0E B3 5E 5C   63 2A 63 EC 85 82 40 DA  ..dJ..^\c*c...@.
  0020: 4B 9B 73 BE 49 AE 1C 14   D6 E6 C2 9A 06 96 18 21  K.s.I..........!
```

Custom logger output:

```
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.508 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 5712
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.508 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.508 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.509 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.509 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.510 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.523 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.524 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log Raw read
28-Jun-2022 16:26:09.524 FINE [http-nio-8081-exec-5] sun.security.ssl.SSLLogger.log READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 5712
```

After checking sources of few files marked in native logger, i.e. [SSLSocketInputRecord.java](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLSocketInputRecord.java), [X509TrustManagerImpl.java](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java) i have noticed that there is additional check for specific logging properties mentioned in logger help (plaintext, record, etc), which is checked like this:

```
if (SSLLogger.isOn && SSLLogger.isOn("ssl,trustmanager")) {
            SSLLogger.fine("adding as trusted certificates",
                    (Object[])trustedCerts.toArray(new X509Certificate[0]));
        }
```

And, while using custom logger SSLLogger.isOn is true, no native logging properties are defined, which means that **with custom logger configured no specific verbose messages will be outputted** by SSLLogger...

p.s. i couldn't manage to use log4j as a custom logger for SSLLogger. (I suppose to do that i need to configure Tomcat to use log4j rather than java.util.logging for all Tomcat's internal logging as noted in [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html).)

Comment: Did you try [`log4j-jpl`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jpl/index.html)?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you, for a tip. I haven't tried that, because this problem has a low priority and project uses log4j 1 EOL...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have log4j.properties file in class-path (/WEB-INF/classes/) with following content:

#### log4j.properties file

```
datestamp=yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/zzz
roll.pattern.hourly=.MM-dd-yyyy.HH
roll.pattern.daily=.MM-dd-yyyy

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Console
log4j.logger=INFO, Console

log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Console.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.Console.file=${catalina.home}/logs/Console.log
log4j.appender.Console.MaxFileSize=800KB
log4j.appender.Console.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %m%n

log4j.appender.custom=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.custom.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.custom.File=${catalina.home}/logs/custom.log
log4j.appender.custom.MaxFileSize=800KB
log4j.appender.custom.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.custom.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.custom.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5p %m%n

log4j.logger.net.javax=DEBUG, custom
```

This will write your log entries into tomcat home directory /logs/custom.log

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This will redirect log4j entries but will do nothing for the SSL debug log (javax.net.debug=all). This answer doesn't relate to the original question.